# Why can't I declare a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to declare a 2D array, a, with the size of 4 x 4 based on the #define SIZE = 4, however I would get an error saying that 'S' is undefined and "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier".

```
#define SIZE 4; 

void findDiagonals(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int *diag1, int *diag2);
```

Comment: Try replacing `S` with `SIZE`?

Comment: No `;` in `#define`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using #define correctly.
`#define SIZE 4` Then check if the error exists.Don't give a colon after #define. At least try to learn the syntax. Check K&R.

Comment: @user1758596 No colon after #define. Check it now. There will be no error.